# Alternative to Cordova

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Is there any alternative to Cordova?

I am creating a simple Android application in Eclipse. I have to use cordova.js and import org.apache.cordova.Config and org.apache.cordova.DroidGap everytime.

Is there any other method without using this Phonegap Cordova implementations.

Comment: Do you want to develop Native or Hybrid ? Which alternatives do you want ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. Hybrid app.

Comment: Whatever framework you use to build hybrid apps, you will have their respective js files and css to achieve functions. Most combine with phonegap in the end to use device api's, so it it better to go with phonegap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many alternatives are available to Phonegap for hybrid development.

I have worked with Ionic, it is a good framework as is using AngularJS and ionic Framework for design, but native support is not there so no device api's. Others such as Titanium SDK and Sencha Touch are available, you will take time to get well with them. Are faster than Phonegap in some areas, also device api support is available.

Whatever framework you use to build hybrid apps, you will have their respective js files and css to achieve functions. Some combine with phonegap in the end to use device api's, so it is better to go with Phonegap or something like Titanium or Sencha.

http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/titanium-sdk/

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch

http://ionicframework.com/

Comment: Can we do away these third party apps and do something with our own code to attain the same?

Comment: What do you mean by doing away these third party apps ? These are frameworks, and are meant to provide the native feel to hybrid apps and also to achieve device functionalities. You may use your own css and js and use it in your app by loading through webview, but then it would look like a website loading on a app. So to develop hybrid app, you must utilise these frameworks. A most common example being : to achieve gestures i.e slide menu on swipe, camera, gps etc in hybrid you will need these frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

In phonegap you put html,css,javascript,jquery in https://build.phonegap.com/apps than it will generate IPA for iphone , apk for android, etc.

so it is also good way to develop Hybrid App.

Link:

https://build.phonegap.com/apps